# TableView edit mode and cells style

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Strange thing: when activates Edit Mode, cells ***with .default style*** have smoothly move animation.

However, cells  ***with style .subtitle*** haven't "swipeable" animation.

Is this normally? SetEditing established to (true, true).

GetCell method:

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Reuse Identifier");

        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, "Reuse Identifier");
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = sections[indexPath.Section].EnglishWords[indexPath.Row];
        cell.TextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(13, 11, 51);

        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = sections[indexPath.Section].RussianWords[indexPath.Row];
        cell.DetailTextLabel.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(69, 68, 68);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `haven't "swipeable" animation.` mean ? You can provide a screenshot .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT when I press "Edit" I waiting that all cells smoothly goes to right. Cells with .subtitle style behaves themeself as I set Editing to (true, false). I mean they just have not animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `setEditing(true,false)`.It is the expected result without animation.

The second params of the method is `Animation` . True to animate the transition to or from editing mode, or false to change modes .

As we can see in the following image .Which is from Apple Developer documentation .

[image]

Comment: As I already wrote, I set animated parameter to true. Problem is that cell styled .subtitle can't be animated. Think is bug

Comment: Can you provide a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .because I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: While I was writing you sample, I realized that problem in expanding header, It my fault that I haven't shared with all of code. Thanks

Comment: You know, in my case it's such a rare mistake, that I won't post it. But of course,  I will accept your common